# Selection of test's last attempt from students

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with information from students and tests, every time a student takes a test a record is saved in this table, so I want to get the last attempt from the students of one test.

```
| IdStudent | IdTest | Attempt|
-------------------------------
| 1         | 1      | 1      |
-------------------------------
| 2         | 1      | 1      |
-------------------------------
| 1         | 1      | 2      |
-------------------------------
| 2         | 2      | 1      |
```

Let's say if I select the test number 1 the records I want to get are the 2 and 3, if I select test 2 the record I want to get is 4, etc.

I hope the question is clear.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following SQL will get you what you want:

```
SELECT IdStudent, IdTest, MAX(Attempt)
FROM StudentTable
WHERE IdTest = @TestNumber
GROUP BY IdStudent, IdTest
```

Comment: @Conrad: good point.  I also didn't use a CTE or self join becasue there is no other data in the table that Argons gave us nor did he tell us that there is any other data

Comment: true... but he did say "records" implying "rows".  Who knows?

Answer (score 2):

@Jeff's answer will get you the numbers but not the rows.  If you want other data in the row you have to use a sub-query or CTE.  Something like this:

```
WITH JeffAnswer AS
(
  SELECT IdStudent, IdTest, MAX(Attempt) AS MaxAttept
  FROM StudentTable
  WHERE IdTest = @TestNumber
  GROUP BY IdStudent, IdTest
)
SELECT * 
FROM StudentTable S
INNER JOIN JeffAnswer J ON
   S.IdStudent = J.IdStudent AND 
   S.IdTest = J.IdTest AND 
   S.Attempt = J.MaxAttempt
```

Answer (score 0):

Some alternative approaches to Jeff Hornby's:

```
Select ...
From Table As T1
Where Exists    (
                Select 1
                From Table As T2
                Where T2.IdStudent = T1.IdStudent
                    And T2.IdTest =T1.IdTest
                Having Max(T2.Attempt) = T1.Attempt
                )
```

If you are using SQL Server 2005+:

```
With RankedTests As
    (
    Select IdStudent, IdTest, Attempt, ...
        , Row_Number() Over ( Partition By IdStudent, IdTest
                                 Order By Attempt Desc ) As Num
    From Table
    )
Select ...
From RankedTests
Where Num = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I like using RowNumber() in cases like this because it's easy to change the criteria later and it's often faster than using a GROUP BY.

```
SELECT IdStudent, IdTest, Attempt  
  FROM (
          SELECT IdStudent, IdTest, Attempt, RowId = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY IdStudent, IdTest ORDER BY IdStudent, IdTest, Attempt Desc)  
            FROM Student  
           WHERE IdTest = @IdTest
       ) tt  
 WHERE tt.RowId = 1
```